# State not updating inside async function in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Expected:
Following useEffect fetches a list of pool addresses when first rendered and assigns it to `getPoolsList`, which should then be used to set `poolsList` state.

```
const [poolsList, setPoolsList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchPools() {
            const getPoolsList = await discountmain.methods.allPool().call();
            console.log(getPoolsList); //returns ['0x...']
            setPoolsList(getPoolsList);
        }
        fetchPools();
}, []);
```

The following code I added to check the value of `poolsList` whenever its value changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useeffect", poolsList); // returns []
}, [poolsList]);
```

However, `poolsList` is showing `[]`.
The file is https://codeshare.io/j0wBLD.
What am I doing wrong? I'm a newbie in React.

Comment: Are you sure it's not logging more than once, and later on it has the value? If `getPoolsList` really contains the value, there's nothing I'm seeing that should cause your useEffect log to not work too.

Comment: its seems ok to me. is there more log information you cloud give or put this in the sandbox so we can look at on it

Comment: the complete file you can view here https://codeshare.io/j0wBLD

Comment: `{renderPoolsCards()}` on line 107. Was debugging before but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but React can be finicky with arrays in the dependency array

First thing is to actually make sure that the data changes and the `useEffect` hook is not being called

Here are few things you can try:

1. Probably the best solution: [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)
2. Use the array length and watch the length

   ```
     const [poolsList, setPoolsList] = useState([]);
     const [poolsListLength, setPoolListLength] = useState(0);

     useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchPools() {
            const getPoolsList = await discountmain.methods.allPool().call();
            console.log(getPoolsList); //returns ['0x...']
            setPoolsList(getPoolsList);
            setPoolListLength(getPoolList.length)
        }
        fetchPools();
   }, []);
   ```

   then

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log("useeffect", poolsList); // returns []
   }, [poolsListLength]);
   ```
3. Use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
4. Not my favorite, but you can Stringify the array

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log(outcomes)
   }, [JSON.stringify(outcomes)])
   ```

Comment: File: codeshare.io/j0wBLD Shows TypeError: poolsSummary.map is not a function. poolsSummary gets its value from `renderPoolsSummary()`. But `renderPoolsSummary()` returns empty, meaning poolsListLength is `0`. Please help me identify where the issue is. I did your 2nd approach.

Comment: I am glad you this is helping you at least debug.
Notice that you are calling poolsSummary.map in the global scope. It does not exist there.
So `undefined.map` is not a function, as the error states

Highly recommend debugging your code first and going through the variables and ask another question if needed